# log4j doesn't create backup files

Tags: java, log4j

I have two jar files on the same classpath, so they are using the same log4j.xml. One of the projects where the xml file is in, rolls it's log file as I expected, but no the other project.

I have configured the xml to create 10 backup files with 1096K, but the backup files aren't being created and the main log file are being erased when the max size is reached.

log4j.xml:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%c.%M()]: %m %n"></param>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/arqGUI.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="4096KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%c.%M()]: %m %n"></param>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE_SERVICE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/arqService.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1096KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%c.%M()]: %m %n"></param>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="com.emp.sin.orcmultemp.service" additivity="false" >
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_SERVICE" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Use of log4j:

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MainClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MainClass.class);
    LOGGER.info("TEST");
}
```

Comment: "I have two jar files on the same classpath, so they are using the same log4j.xml". Are you sure? What do you mean by "projects"? It could easily be that you reference the log4j configuration file in such a way that one project finds it and not the other.

Comment: @JP Moresmau, both two projects are finding the configuration, beacuse when I make some change on the xml, takes effect in both projects.

Comment: Do you mean that `arqGui.log` rolls but `arqService.log` doesn't? Or are you running two separate Java processes, each creating two logs in different `log` directories?

Comment: As an aside, why are you setting the `LevelRangeFilter` instead of properly setting the level on the loggers?

Comment: @erickson I have two project, one creates arqGui.log and the other creates arqService.log. Only arqGui.log rolls. The project that creates arqService.log finds the xml, erases the log when reaches the limit, but does not create the backup.

Comment: "Project" doesn't mean anything. Are there two separate `java` processes running? How many log files are created? 2 or 4?

Comment: Yes, there are two java processes running, each one in a separate project, but using the same log4j.xml. 2 log falies are created.